# How smart is it to send emails via CLR enable (c# dll) with SQL Server 2008?

Tags: c#, sql-server, software-design

My question is about **abstract software engineer point of view** :

Suppose I want to send an email after each insertion of row to a table.

Which approach will be smarter and "by the book" ?

1. create a C#/CLR assembly which will send mail
2. enable the CLR in SQL Server
3. create trigger after insert, using that assembly's function to send mail

**or**

1. in C# application program itself , after the insertion to DB  - send the email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Database Mail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175887.aspx), which is a built in emailing solution for SQL Server, if you're going to do the emailing from the server (rather than writing your own solution).

This, at least, ensures that delivery of mail is asynchronous with respect to the rest of your transaction, so would be safe to call from a trigger or stored proc, without breaking either of these if the email delivery takes a while to succeed.

---

As to, now, the decision of *whether* you should use this, called from a trigger or stored proc, or do the work in the application, it depends on which you're more comfortable with. In either case, you need to consider the various failure conditions rather than just the happy path. If the SQL portion succeeds, and then the application crashes (or is killed through task manager) before it sends the email, how serious a failure would that be? What mitigating steps would you have to put in place?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Damien that if you really want to do in inside the database you should rather use **Database Mail**.

My suggestion is to do it anyway from your C# application because I think from there you have way better control.

what if you at some point insert 100.000 records at once or in multiple consecutive transactions?

Doing the emailing from your code (it's very easy with SMTP Mails in .NET), you can have methods which suit all your requirements, some sending email after a single insert and some others sending the message after a bunch of inserts has been completed.

I am also, in general, a bit against triggers, I prefer to leave the database alone and except stored procs not making it to do too much; much easier to debug and follow/trace/log what happens in the client (or server) .NET application.

here were my two cents, everyone could have different approach.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to consider is for what and for whom the emails are intended. If you are sending a small maintenance message if an exception or warning condition occurs, then a synchronous mechanism might be the simplest solution if volumes aren't high.

But if you need to mail high quality reports (e.g. PDF with personalised HTML) then would recommend that you queue up the tasks for 'mails to be sent' e.g. in a table, and then create and despatch the emails asynchronously e.g. using SSRS, Crystal etc. This will also have benefits of a better audit trail and the ability to change channels (e.g. print instead of email) without breaking your SQL 'queueing' mechanism.